# How to get UUID for VMware VM in vSphere 6.5 Python vCenter API?

Tags: vmware, vcenter

I'm trying to get UUID for the VMware VM using Python vCenter API.

I'm reading GET VM API doc [here](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/v7.0.0/vcenter/rest/vcenter/vm/vm/get/#response-body). which says It should be there in the response but when I run get API I don't get identity in the response. Anyone has any idea why it's not returning identity in the response payload?

```
"identity": {
            "bios_uuid": "string",
            "instance_uuid": "string",
            "name": "string"
    }
```

API I'm using https://{api_host}/rest/vcenter/vm/{vm}

Answer (score 0):

The full name of that set of properties is "[guest identity](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/v7.0.0/vcenter/rest/vcenter/vm/vm/guest/identity/get/)" which will also mean that VMware Tools are installed and running at the time of the call.

Comment: It seems like that's not an option for my use case. Do you know any alternative way to get UUID of the VM?